# How to add round corners to a Circular Progress Bar in Android?

Tags: android, layout, progress-bar

Hello I am trying to design a Circular bar progess component. I have managed to do this, but I can't get to design the circle round corners.

For the moment I have this:

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QOVZ.jpg)

Here is the code that I am using:

custom_progress_drwawable.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="16"
            android:useLevel="false"
            android:thickness="10dp">
            <solid android:color="@color/base_dark" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="270"
            android:toDegrees="270">
            <shape
                android:shape="ring"
                android:thicknessRatio="16"
                android:useLevel="true"
                android:thickness="10dp">
                <gradient
                    android:endColor="@color/secundary_10"
                    android:type="radial"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

circular_progress_bar

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        style="@style/CircularDeterminateProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:progress="100"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:textSize="12sp"
        app:textColor="@color/blue_dark"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/progress_bar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/progress_bar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/progress_bar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/progress_bar"
        tools:text="60%" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And what I want to get is this(the same but with round corners bar):

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqGKh.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using a [Material CircularProgressIndicator](https://material.io/components/progress-indicators/android#circular-progress-indicators) by setting the `app:trackCornerRadius` to change the Track Corner Radius.

1.First get the latest Material Design Library and add it into your app dependencies (`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'`)

2.In your xml layout use the `com.google.android.material.progressindicator.CircularProgressIndicator` like below:

```
<com.google.android.material.progressindicator.CircularProgressIndicator
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:progress="25"
    app:trackCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:indicatorSize="90dp"
    app:trackThickness="7dp"
    app:trackColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
    app:indicatorColor="@android:color/black"
    app:indicatorDirectionCircular="clockwise"
    app:indicatorInset="5dp"/>
```

Based on your layout replace the `ProgressBar` with `CircularProgressIndicator` like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <com.google.android.material.progressindicator.CircularProgressIndicator
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:progress="25"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:indicatorSize="90dp"
        app:trackCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:trackThickness="7dp"
        app:trackColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:indicatorColor="@android:color/black"
        app:indicatorDirectionCircular="clockwise"
        app:indicatorInset="5dp"
        tools:progress="25"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="25%"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/progress_bar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/progress_bar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/progress_bar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/progress_bar"
        tools:text="25%" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Result:**

[image: Circular ProgressBar]

Comment: but how can we use gradient color for indicator?

Comment: @iffanmajid, are you got the solution?

Comment: @MehulDhimmar hope [this article](https://medium.com/glose-team/a-glowing-progress-ring-with-rounded-ends-for-android-865eb0161cc1) can help